# Bash Shell Syntax issue with Multiple IF Condition

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am confused with Multiple condition in single IF clause statement.

If I use following syntax it throws error.

```
if [[ [ "$a" == "" && "$b" != "" ] && [ "$b" == "" ] ]]; 
then echo 1; 
else echo 2; 
fi
```

> -bash: [: missing `]'

But if I replace `[` to `(` only inside condition its working as below

```
if [[ ( "$a" == "" && "$b" != "" ) && ( "$b" == "" ) ]];
```

Can any one say why its so confusing and why it is designed like this ? I am confused with usage of different kind of braces [ ( . when to use [ and when not to use (.

Comment: Which one is easier for you?

Comment: The 'confusing' bit is actually `[` which was historically a program (even though long since implemented in shells) and had/has .. limitations. The `[[` is 'special bash' with advanced support for expressions, including parenthesis. Just use `[[ bash_expression_with_parenthesis_here ]]` and life will be good again.

Comment: @Mat : I am confused with usage of different kind of braces [ ( . when to use [ and when not to use (.

Comment: @AvinashRaj : I prefer `if [[ [ "$a" == "" && "$b" != "" ] && [ "$b" == "" ] ]]; `

Comment: @user2864740 : Thanks . but when to use single `[` ? if i use like this, it again shows syntax error. `if [ ( "$b" == "" ) ]; then echo 1; else echo 2; fi                  -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"$b"'` but the same is working when i replace with double `[[`

Comment: Because `[` has to maintain compatibility with old shell behavior. `[[` is bash syntax and is newer / more powerful (and specific to bash) - and in this case provides the expected syntax (with `test` you'll need to use `-a` and `-o` instead of `&&` and `||`, respectively). The [details on Bash can be found here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html). The details on `[` (also known as `test`) can be [found here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test).

Comment: @user2864740 : I tested with `&& ||`.. its working fine so why should i only use `-a -o` ?

Comment: When do you expect your if statement is true? When `"$b" != ""` the last part is false and when `"$b" == ""` the first part is false.

Comment: @user2864740 Even the POSIX spec recommends against using `-a` and `-o` as Boolean operators for a single `test` command; use two `test`s joined by `&&` and `||` instead. (That is, `[ "$a" = "" ] && [ "$b" = "" ]`.)

Comment: @chepner While it would work in this case with dropping the explicit grouping, it doesn't allow the use of parenthesis around the logic operators or the ability to represent `a || (b && c)` cleanly.

Comment: @user2864740: so post it as answer I will accept it..

Comment: You can still group tests: `{ a; } || { b && c; }` (where `a`, `b`, and `c` are `test` commands).

Comment: @chepner Ah, that's pretty cool. Do you have a link to the/a POSIX recommendation against -a/-o?

Comment: So nobody adding the answer to get 10 points ?